Is there grammatical "agreement" in English beyond subject-verb agreement?
If it's not evident, by "agreement" I mean the phenomenon where related words undergo inflection so that their values (commonly number, gender and person) are the same, or "agree" with each other.  Compared to other languages, modern English is said to have little agreement in it.  The most known is, of course, subject-verb agreement (I am, we are, you are, etc).  The Wikipedia article on agreement mentions number agreement between demonstrative determiners and nouns (this/that woman and these/those women).  The question is, are there any other instances (in modern English)?  Thanks in advance.

"He hurt his knee" often refers to a self-inflicted injury, but "he hurt her knee" is more likely to be assault.

@ishtar 'They saw themself' is also possible nowadays (when the gender of the singular  subject referent is unknown).

The most obvious case is pronoun-antecedent agreement in gender and number.
For instance, consider these two sentences:

The baby has lost its rattle.
* The child has lost its rattle.

(1) is correct (though his/her could also be used), but (2) is wrong, even though "the baby" and "the child" could well be referring to the same person. This illustrates that the choice of pronouns in English depends not only on the antecedent's denotation but also on its linguistic form. These constraints on which inflectional forms of pronouns can be used with which antecedents justify the use of the term "agreement" to describe the relationship between them.
My source, as usual, is Huddleston & Pullum (2002), in this case pp. 484-486.

but (2) is wrong, - I feel that this has been plucked out of thin air by H&P and, to quote Hitchins, "That which is stated without evidence can be dismissed without evidence." -> His/her/its and their" are all possible.

... 'Its' is rare here but far from unknown. The Child and Its Enemies ...  Author: Emma Goldman / The Child and Its Family: 2 (Genesis of Behavior ... M. Lewis / The child and its environment ... Medicine and Surgery, RAED library; translation / ....

Agreement between adjective and noun as to whether the noun is mass or count.

Not many chairs were there.
Not much furniture was there.

"Chairs" is count and may thus take "many", but may not take "much". The reverse is true of "furniture".

It's more complex than this. With count noun usages, verb form certainly agrees with noun form (arguably with possible logical overrides such as 'chicken and chips is on the menu', though countness is moot here). But there non-count noun usages with singular form taking a plural verb form ('police are looking for a Bugatti') (note that the plural form is 'polices', which does exist). And there are non-count noun usages with plural form taking a singular verb form ('the data is looking useful' / 'statistics is an important subject' / 'It is Friday, and sports is scheduled for later in the day).
